# How to display values inside multi-dimensional array in php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I would like to get the values of id and name inside this array.

```
Array
(
[data] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [id] => 238345159549706
                [members] => Array
                    (
                        [data] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => Array
                                    (
                                        [id] => 100001130889528
                                        [name] => Sy Cheeze
                                    )
                                [1] => Array
                                    (
                                        [id] => 100002616426665
                                        [name] => Chun Jenny
                                    )
                                    .......
```

I've tried using this foreach.

```
  foreach ($acquaintances as $acquaintance)
    {
      foreach ($acquaintance as $acquaint)
      {
        $acqID = $acquaint['id'];
        $acqName = $acquaint['name'];

        echo $acqName;
      }
    }
```

but nothing will be displayed. What would I do with my code? Any idea and suggestions please. Thank you!

Comment: check my answer bellow,and let me know if it is what you need

Answer (score 1):

```
$array = array
   (
   array("bla",22,18),
   array("blaa",15,13),
   array("blaaa",5,2),
   array("blaaaa",17,15)
   );

for ($row = 0; $row <  4; $row++) {
   echo "<p><b>Row number $row</b></p>";
   echo "<ul>";
   for ($col = 0; $col <  3; $col++) {
     echo "<li>".$array[$row][$col]."</li>";
   }
   echo "</ul>";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also access the indices directly in your foreach loop. Like this:

```
foreach($acquaintances['data'] as $acquaintance) {
    foreach($acquaintance['members']['data'] as $acquaint) {
        $acqID = $acquaint['id'];
        $acqName = $acquaint['name'];

        echo $acqName . '<br/>';
    }
}
```